# 条件付き書式の設定

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

gasで条件付き書式の設定をしたいのですが、
それらしい機能が見当たりません。

まだ、実装されていないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リファレンスを確認しましたが GoogleAppsScript で条件付き書式を設定する機能は今のところ無さそうですね。
（あるとしたら Range クラスだと思うのですが）

GoogleAppsScript で実現するとしたら、

- あらかじめ条件付き書式を用意しておき [copyFormatToRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangegridid-column-columnend-row-rowend) でコピーする
- onEdit() イベントで書式変更する

くらいしか思いつかないですね。

ちなみに以下コードは copyFormatToRange() のサンプルです。
「from」シートB2:D4 の書式を「to」シートB2:D4 にコピーしてます。

```
function myFunction() {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetFrom = ss.getSheetByName("from");
 var sheetTo   = ss.getSheetByName("to");

 var range = sheetFrom.getRange("B2:D4");
 range.copyFormatToRange(sheetTo.getSheetId(), 2, 4, 2, 4);

}
```